# Erlang erlang-rfc4627 strange error

Tags: json, erlang

Hi I've been using rfc4627 for erlang now ive had this slice of code working before but now after ive made changes to the way things are passed i get a Error in process *** on node '@127.0.0.1' with exit value: {{badmatch,{obj,[{c,1}]}}

Here is the code

```
-define(TO_SELF, fun(S, M, T) -> Msg = {obj, M}, ?LOG("OUTGOING: ~p~n", [Msg]), ok end).
```

where M is Msg=[{c,1}],

does anyone have any idea what can be causing it ive been trying all day with no luck.
Thanks
Dave

Comment: i just tried passing Msg={obj, [{c,1}]}, to the function removing the Msg var from the define and it works now but i would like to not have to pass the full object to the function

Comment: Can you post your full code and also the full error message? It looks like you are reusing a variable which is causing the badmatch.

Comment: My full code looks like this currently

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Q3foCOS.png
http://i.imgur.com/pXa6pqB.png

Comment: the define is in another file not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: the above screenshots all work fine but as the answer states below looks like its a programming limit of some kind :)

Comment: It makes no difference that the define is in another file, it expands the same. Your new code has removed that match, but it probably was the cause of the error. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably the variable scoping rules of funs in Erlang which is causing your problem. Any *free* variables in the fun body which have been bound before the fun is defined will have their value imported into the fun. The fun is a closure so this is common to most languages with closures, it is in fact one of the things which make funs/closures so powerful.

So if `Msg` is already bound when you define the fun,

```
Msg = foo,
F = ?TO_SELF,
...
```

its value is then imported and `Msg = {obj,M}` does not bind `Msg` but tests against it value, `foo` in the example.

Comment: This is properly the case as your answer makes much more sense than any of mine ;)

Comment: So say i have a var named His in a different file but in another file say a .hrl i define it again the error would occur again

Comment: a var has a scope limited to the function where it is defined, so there is few risk with variable namming. In your example you use a -define which works like string replacement (I mean it is not parsed/analyzed in the hrl file but in the function where it used),and a fun where the internal Msg variable is already bound: so you get something like Msg = {obj, Msg} which does not match. In my opinion the danger came from using macro with hidden variables (and worse, having very common name).

Comment: yea when i got into bed last night it clicked and i realized what you was saying basicly if i used a different var name it would have proberly worked fine, you said this above (but in the function where it used) so my brain said stop trying to overwrite vars :)